# CoordinatorLayout scroll Tablayout itself

Tags: scroll, android-recyclerview, android-tablayout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I want to have an activity, which contains a TabLayout and a Viewpager and some stuff below the Viewpager, which is visible in every Tab, and also scrollable.

When the recyclerview "tracks_recyclerview" is scrolled up, the TabLayout and the Edittext and the Viewpager hide as they should and the "all_tracks"-relativelayout and the horizontal Recyclerview stay at the top.

Here is what i want:

The content above the recyclerview should also be scrollable itself. So for now it is only possible to scroll down the "tracks_recyclerview". but the other parts of the view should also scroll down the list.

My Code looks something like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/content_activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/transparent">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:tabContentStart="2dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
            app:tabMinWidth="24dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabPadding="1dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="#444"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/all_tracks"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="155dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/cover"
                    android:layout_width="140dp"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                    android:paddingTop="20dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/abc_btn_rating_star_on_mtrl_alpha" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="140dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/cover"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

<?-- horizontal Recyclerview -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="155dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/all_tracks" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/tracks_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I Hope you could understand my problem and maybe help me out.

Thanks,
Thomas

Edit: Is there somebody who can help me?